# Google Play shows Sony Tablet S as incompatible for my app

Tags: android, google-play, sony

I have an application live in Google Play for more than a year and recently a user reported that he has a Sony Tablet S and Google Play shows him that my app is not compatible with this device.

I read through many threads in stackoverflow regarding incompatible issues, and as far as I could understand it usually happens (based on my research on various stackoverflow threads) for one of the following 4 reasons

1. Size of the application is large (larger than some limit specified on the device).
2. Due to the supported screen sizes specified in the manifest
3. Google play filters out app based on some implied features for the permissions requested in the app.
4. Filtered based on min sdk specified in the manifest

As far as I know , none of the above should be applicable for my app because

1. Size of the app is less than 1mb
2. I have not specified any supported screen sizes in the manifest
3. I have only requested 3 permissions in the manifest (INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and based on android documentation these permissions don't seem to have any implied user-features. (I could be wrong here). I wonder if there was a need to explicitly mention all of these permissions as optional, but couldn't find any way to do that since there are no implied user-features for these.
4. Min sdk is is 8, which is lower than the one supported by Sony Tablet S (API Level 15 I believe). I have not specified any max sdk version.

Here is the section from my manifest which has permissions etc.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />        
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

I'm at a loss as to what might be prompting Google Play to show my app as incompatible on Sony Tablet S for the user.  When I go to google developer console and look at the supported devices, Sony Tablet S is listed as supported, but apparently for the user it appears as incompatible.

Any leads to narrow down this issue is highly appreciated. FYI. App works fine on many other tablets - Kindle Fire, Galaxy Tab, Asus etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try explicitly declaring that you app supports xlarge screen sizes:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true">
```

By default this is not always set to true.

Comment: Thanks , will try it and see what happens. If I add support screens for one screen size, does it mean I dont support other screen sizes? In other words, if I specify one, do I need to explicitly specify all other screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't mean that you don't support other sizes.  By default your app will support small and normal screens but it's best to set it explicitly for large and xlarge screens since it can vary depending on device.  See here for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html